# GeoServer: Receive multiple tiles from layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, tiles, wmts

Using GeoServer you can do a WMS request to receive a single PNG representation of a certain layer using something like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=spearfish&styles=&bbox=589425.9342365642,4913959.224611808,609518.6719560538,4928082.949945881&width=512&height=359&srs=EPSG:26713&format=image%2Fpng
```

Is it possible to alter this request to directly request different "zoom levels" or "tiles" of the layer? I assume you need to do a `Web Map Tile Service (WMTS`) request but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a 256*256 PNG tile of a certain map service from geoserver you can do it with including tiled=TRUE in your request:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=spearfish&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=true&TILESORIGIN=589425.93423656%2C4913959.2246118&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A26713&BBOX=589425.93423656,4913959.2246118,609518.67195605,4934051.9623313&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256
```

But there's no zoom parameter in the request, and the client side application will take care of the certain zoom level and the bounding box.

But if you insist on using WMTS (which capability is included in GeoServer with GeoWebCache integration) you can do it with the following request:

```
http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=medford%3Abuildings&STYLE=_null&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG%3A900913&TILEMATRIX=EPSG%3A900913%3A13&TILEROW=3030&TILECOL=1300&FORMAT=image%2Fpng
```

Here the TILEROW and TILECOL are the key parameters. But if you want to extend your knowledge about WMTS I would suggest you to check out the official OGC standard here:

http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts

And you can find useful information about WMTS in geoserver at the following link:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/defaults.html?highlight=wmts

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to store multiple tiles from a map service before using something like OpenLayers to render them. But this just isn't possible it seems...

Comment: It's possible... there are two expressions for "storing multiple tiles from a map service": caching and seeding refers to saving your map in different zoom levels as small tiles. You should search for these two expression. But with GeoServer you should use GeoWebCache, please check the documentation of it here: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/index.html Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. So I seeded the map and started using the TIREROW and TILECOL parameters but I can still only reach the tiles of the top most zoom level, not the tiles from different zoom levels. Same goes for that example from http://v2.suite.opengeo.org, the range is really small: "Row 3016 is out of range, min: 3074 max:3081" What am I missing?

Comment: O nevermind! The zoomlevel was inside the TILEMATRIX parameter.