# How to return multiple tiles from WMTS request

Tags: geoserver, wmts

Using the WMTS 'GetTile' request, I have been able to retrieve *individual* tiles from a layer (as specified by values supplied in the tilecol and tilerow paramaters).

Is it possible to retrieve multiple tiles (i.e. for example, an entire layer) through a WMTS request?  I've reviewed the answer supplied here: [GeoServer: Receive multiple tiles from layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56633/geoserver-receive-multiple-tiles-from-layer), but found even using this guidance I could still only retrieve an individual tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR; No**

Longer answer - No, a GetTile request is part of the [OGC WMTS specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) and is designed to allow you to request **one** (and **only one**) tile - there is no way to indicate to the server anything other than a single identifying triple (X,Y,Z).